# Comparing the percentage changes of two Crosstabs (Chi-square test of independence/association)

Tags: chi-squared-test, independence, association-measure

I'm looking for an association between 2 variables before and after manipulation. I ran 2 separate crosstabs and I'm able to see for which cells there's an association. Additionally, I want to see whether the association change from before (part1) to after (part2) manipulation is significant. I'm attaching a screenshot that shows a part of the crosstabs. For example, in part1 the percentage for female HeHc bottom_center is 70.1% and in part2 it is 67.4%. Can I just say there's a decrease of frequency after manipulation for females, or do I need to do an additional analysis, if so, which one?

Thank you in advance!

[image: 2 crosstabs results part1 and part2]